# Cannot verify Test API Credentials when configuring Okta User provisioning

Tags: single-sign-on, servicenow, okta-api

I am configuring Okta User Provisioning (developer account) in relation to a ServiceNow instance. Even after passing the correct user id and password, I am unable to verify the 'Test API Credentials'.

## I receive below validation error:

Could not verify the ServiceNow administrator login and password; please confirm that these are set correctly.

Any suggestion what could be wrong here?

Comment: Where are you trying to configure user provisioning using username password? Which record or plugin are you using for doing this?

Comment: May be you can follow the process given at this link to use Multiprovider SSO plugin to setup SSO to your instance.

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/single-sign-on/task/t_SettingUpMultiProviderSSO.html

Comment: I am adding this username and password on Okta side as these credentials will be used by Okta to get in ServiceNow so as to push the user data.